# She IS a two-time Academy Award nominee vs He WAS the champion of 2015 competition

Tags: past-simple, compounds, postpositive-adjectives

I was strolling on the Wikipedia page and saw phrases like

> She **is** a two-time Academy Award nominee. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saoirse_Ronan)

and

> He **was** the champion of 2015 competition.

I would like to know which one is correct? and why? Sometimes, I am confused with when to use **is** and when to use **was**.

Comment: This question is better asked (and will receive more helpful answers) on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is whether the honor is transient or lasting. Discerning which is which is a fuzzy area and beyond the scope of this question. But:

For transient honors, such as sports championships, you *are* the champion until you are defeated. And then the honor moves into the past tense.

For lasting honors, such as the achievement of a rank, you make the present/past distinction not with the verb, but by modifying the noun. E.G. Current:

> This year's best actor nominee [name here]...

vs former:

> Seven-time Academy Award nominee [name here]...

Also, current:

> United Nations Ambassador [name here]...

vs former

> Former ambassador [name here]...

Answer (score 0):

You can use either and the meaning will be the same. The thing is, both tenses are valid. For the first, we're referring to a body of work, and thus, the accomplishments are permanent, and considered present tense. e.g. Michael Jordan is a 6 time NBA Finals MVP. You could also say he *was* a 6 time Finals MVP.

The player won the 2015 competition in the past (so was is appropriate), and *is* a two time champion/reigning champion. It all depends on your context.

Comment: And whether the subject is alive or dead. And if it can occur again or not.

Comment: This is a good point of clarification that I missed, but I don't know if it paints the whole picture. For example: "Muhammad Ali has a boxing record of 56 wins with 5 losses." Ali is dead, and he won't box again, but it's still his existing body of work.

Comment: As you said, it depends on context. But I would use 'had' instead of 'has' in your Ali example since he cannot change his record now that he has passed. Pretty much the only time I would use the present form of a verb with a dead subject would in a narrative.